# Disabling a script once target location is reached?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, targeting

How can I have my enemy disable a script once it reaches target player? I want to reference this script called casting under my GameManager in my code and disable it but I'm unsure how to write the function for when target location is reached.

```
public float lookRadius = 40f;

Transform target;
UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent agent;

Rigidbody theRigidBody;

void Start()
{
    target = PlayerManager.instance.player.transform;
    agent = GetComponent<UnityEngine.AI.NavMeshAgent>();
}

void Update()
{
    float distance = Vector3.Distance (target.position, transform.position);
    if (distance <= lookRadius)
    {
        agent.SetDestination (target.position);

        if (distance <= agent.stoppingDistance)
        {
            FaceTarget ();
        }
    }
}

void FaceTarget()
{
    Vector3 direction = (target.position - transform.position).normalized;
    Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (new Vector3 (direction.x, 0, direction.z));
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, lookRotation, Time.deltaTime * 5f);
}


// Use this for initialization
public void OnObjectSpawn ()
{
    //myRender = GetComponent<Renderer> ();
    theRigidBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    Gizmos.color = Color.red;
    Gizmos.DrawWireSphere (transform.position, lookRadius);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to obtain the gameobject that has the script, get the script on that gameobject, and disable.

```
if (distance < 1f) // or some distance
{
    Gameobject mygo = GameObject.Find("GameManager"); // or some other method to get gameobject.
    mygo.GetComponent<casting>().enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, how will I detect when target is reached? do I add a function called `public void TargetReached()`?

Comment: you already have the `distance` between the transform and your target. pick a value for how close you need to be.